# Custom Basic Authentication in Camel Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have a `OSGi` bundle which is deployed in Apache Karaf. I am using `BASIC` authentication to check user credentials. Here is my configuration `Spring` file:

```
<beans...>
...
    <bean id="loginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
        <property name="name" value="karaf"/>
        <property name="loginModuleName" value="karaf"/>
        <property name="roleClassNames">
            <list>
                <value>org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.RolePrincipal</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="identityService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultIdentityService"/>

    <bean id="constraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC"/>
        <property name="roles" value="admin"/>
        <property name="authenticate" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="constraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
        <property name="constraint" ref="constraint"/>
        <property name="pathSpec" value="/*"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
        <property name="authenticator">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator"/>
        </property>
        <property name="constraintMappings">
            <list>
                <ref bean="constraintMapping"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="loginService" ref="loginService"/>
        <property name="strict" value="false"/>
        <property name="identityService" ref="identityService"/>
    </bean>

    <camelContext trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8282/services?handlers=securityHandler&amp;matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
            <transform>
                <constant>&lt;html>&lt;body>Hello from Fuse ESB server&lt;/body>&lt;/html></constant>
            </transform>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
    ....
</beans>
```

When I enter this URL: `http://localhost:8282/services` in the browser I see the basic authentication window, requiring username and password. It is OK until this point.

The user credentials is set in the `user.properties` of `Apache Karaf` `&{base.dir}/etc/` directory. From there the authenticator is taking the user credentials to check.

My problem is that I need to override somehow the authenticator to use the credentials from my database. I did not try anything yet to make this work because I have no idea where to start. I have trying searching the internet but there are no clues how to make this work or even where to start, to make this work. So if someone could point me to the right direction on how to do this, that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to pull it out of your own user store, then you'll need to provide your own IdentityService and LoginService and replace them in your example above.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-security/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/security/HashLoginService.java

This is an example of a login service that loads the users from a properties type file and stores them in a hashmap.

You will likely be fine to use the existing BasicAuthenticator as it uses the provided LoginService and IdentityService...so override those and replace them and you ought to be good to go.

There are a number of examples up a directory from the hash example above including a spnego option.

Comment: Actually I did not have to create my own IdentityService, I used the default one. What I did was created my own Login service extended AbstractLifeCycle, implemented the LoginService, implemented the methods of how I need and it works now. I have my users from database. And the basic auth also works. Thanks, you really moved me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using Spring, consider using the Spring Security modules to provide the security for your webapp.

There's even a `JdbcDaoImpl` you can hook up to provide the UserDetailsService for the security
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/core-services.html#d0e2875